# How does the PUSH instruction get its input?

Tags: evm, opcode, transaction-trace, trace

I'm trying to understand state storage, and by doing so (for the first time) looking at raw geth traces. I've hit a blocker, though, which is understanding where the arguments to `PUSH` instructions come from.

[According to evm.codes](https://www.evm.codes/#60) `PUSH1` takes an argument and puts it on the stack. For other opcodes, such as SHA3/KECCAK256, the arguments `offset` and `size` are taken from the stack, and then it reads from memory.

But where does PUSH1 get its argument from?

Comment: PUSH1 gets its argument from the code of the contract, at the offset which is located at the PC + 1 . It only takes  64 bytes. Where it encounters PUSH1, it increments the PC and reads the 64 bytes (from contract code)

Comment: Thank you! You should add that as an answer below so I can accept it

Comment: @Nulik That's correct, except that I think it takes a 1-byte number from the contract code (hence the 1 in PUSH1) and pushes it on the stack as a 32-byte number.

Answer (score 1):

["All EVM instructions take their parameter from the stack, except for PUSHx, which takes their parameters from the code."](https://www.evm.codes/about)